# How to get the "{Binding}" instance from within the behavior?

Tags: xaml, uwp, dependency-properties, behavior

I created a behavior to validate a control whenever there's an **error**. The behavior needs to know the `Binding` (viewmodel) source of the control because the `ViewModel` implements `IDataErrorInfo` and the behavior needs to subscribe to `the ErrorChanged` event to make the appropriate action when an error occurs.

To do that, I added a dependency property ValidationSource which will always be set to `"{Binding}"`.

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding LastName, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}">
  <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
    <b:MyValidateOnErrorBehavior PropertyName="LastName" ValidationSource="{Binding}" />
  </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
</TextBox>
```

This solution works for me but I don't want to type `ValidationSource="{Binding}"` all the time.

Is there a way from within the behavior to get to the `"{Binding}"` instance without having to set it in the dependency property?

Answer (score 0):

In the Behavior's code you can get the AssociatedObject.DataContext to get that - which would be your ViewModel.

Comment: That's not the case when you didn't bind anything to the VM. If you look at my example, there are two properties which is the PropertyName and the ValidationSource. Once I remove the validationSource, there's no more property that is bound to the VM since the PropertyName is a literal string "LastName". If that's the case, when you look at the AssociatedObject.DataContext, it's null.

Comment: AssociatedObject refers to the TextBox and this one has a DataContext regardless of the value of your ValidationSource property, hasn't it?